# Resetting window control buttons to the original in Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, themes

I'm using a Windows 7 laptop for the time being until I can repair my Windows 11 machine. Now I have one question I had once back in 2012.

My window control buttons look like this:
[image]

I want them to look like this: [image]

This computer is an Acer Aspire One 722, and when I retrieved it from storage, the themes may have gone corrupted, as the included themes had missing images and/or won't change the window bar color.
[image]

How do I change the window control buttons on Windows 7 to the default ones (the second image)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I change the window control buttons on Windows 7 to the default ones

You need to choose the Windows 7 Aero Theme:

[image]